# How can I disable the mouse wheel in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome, mouse, gnome-terminal

Does anybody know if it's possible to disable mouse wheel up-down events in gnome-terminal? I have a rather twitchy mouse wheel, and every time it twitches it does a history lookup in my terminal. But I still want to be able to middle-click paste.

Comment: May be [this][1] is what you looking for


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/52389/how-do-i-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-under-ubuntu

Comment: Not really: I use the scroll wheel in browsers etc, so it's just in gnome-terminal I want to disable it.

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you are looking for but have you considered investing a few $/£/¥/whatevers in a new mouse with a more positive action to the scroll wheel?

Comment: It looks like this could be what you were looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278677/disable-scroll-inside-xfce-terminal-avoid-scrolling-through-command-history#278756