# Disable scroll inside Xfce terminal / Avoid scrolling through command history

Tags: terminal, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, xfce4-terminal

Is there a way to disable scrolling through command history for the Xfce terminal? I don't wish to rely on palm rejection, I'd just like it disabled when I'm using the terminal. Specifically I'm talking about not cycling through previous commands at the prompt when scrolling with mouse/touchpad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing the feature of VTE (used in XFCE Terminal) which translates wheel-mouse scrolling into up/down cursor-keys when using the alternate-screen.  That happens if you are running [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) in something like [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/).  You can avoid that by preventing `screen` from using the terminal's alternate screen feature.

For example (see *[How to disable alternate buffer in GNU screen itself but not for vim, less inside it?](https://superuser.com/questions/609402/how-to-disable-alternate-buffer-in-gnu-screen-itself-but-not-for-vim-less-insid)*), tell `screen` that the feature does not exist (by putting this in `.screenrc`):

```
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
```

A similar workaround is used for `tmux` (see *[Properly disable terminal capabilities for alternate screen in tmux](https://daniel.hahler.de/properly-disable-terminal-capabilities-for-alternate-screen-in-tmux)*), putting this in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

This translation of scrolling behavior does not appear to be *configurable* in VTE-based terminals.  It is configurable in `xterm`, e.g., `alternateScroll` ([patch #282](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282)).

Further reading:

- [Make screen work like a terminal (scrolling + alternate screen)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277381/make-screen-work-like-a-terminal-scrolling-alternate-screen)
- [Fixing the alternate screen problem](http://blogmal.42.org/tidbits/titeinhibit.story) (one of many pages pro/con)
- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)

Comment: I use TMUX, does that command work with it too?

Comment: It's the same problem - different details for solution (will see...)

Comment: I'm using ArchLinux, I find it strange that I didn't find termcapinfo with pacman/yaourt, will take a look whether it's part of other named package or a related tool.

Comment: It is the name of a setting in `.screenrc` (configuration for `screen`).

Comment: I've put `set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` on my `.tmux.conf` and reloaded, it didn't work through reloading, so I imagined of course that I needed to restart the tmux process, it worked like a charm, many thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a 'feature' of VTE.  I'd call it a bug.  hard-coding 8 up or down arrows in response to scroll-wheel events **is** a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Edit > Preferences` menu of `xfce4-terminal` you can disable the scrollbar.

If you set the `scrollback` value to 1, it will disable scrolling back using the scroll wheel on your mouse.

I'm using `xfce4-terminal 0.6.3`, the default version for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: My particular issue isn't scrolling the window, but cycling through previous commands, I don't wish this to happen through mouse/touchpad, when I scroll, it's not the window that scrolls, but instead, cycling commands at the prompt.

Comment: After applying the accepted answer, I also need this one to avoid scrooling now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same problem using iTerm on my Mac. Whenever I would use the `screen` feature I was unable to scroll up/down, super annoying.

### To disable the command line history on-scroll, do the following:

1. Open `Preferences` and click on `Advanced` tab
2. Scroll down to the `Mouse` section, or search for "scroll"
3. Locate option `Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode` and  select **No** from the dropdown

And you're all set!